# Duplicate model along with it's associations

Tags: cakephp, model, associations, duplication

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304280/cakephp-newbie-question-how-do-i-duplicate-a-model-and-its-related-data) that gave an answer on how to do this but it's not quite working for me.

I have a model called `SitePage` which has many `SitePageGroup` which in turn has many `SitePageContent`

```
// SitePage Model
public $hasMany = array(
    'SitePageGroup' => array(
        'className' => 'FoCMS.SitePageGroup',
        'foreignKey' => 'site_page_id',
        'dependent' => FALSE,
    ),
);

// SitePageGroup Model
public $belongsTo = array(
    'SitePage' => array(
        'className' => 'FoCMS.SitePage',
        'foreignKey' => 'site_page_id',
    ),
);

public $hasMany = array(
    'SitePageContent' => array(
        'className' => 'FoCMS.SitePageContent',
        'foreignKey' => 'site_page_group_id',
        'dependent' => FALSE,
    ),
);

// SitePageContent Model
public $belongsTo = array(
    'SitePageGroup' => array(
        'className' => 'FoCMS.SitePageGroup',
        'foreignKey' => 'site_page_group_id',
    ),
);
```

Using the answer in that linked question I am seeing the parent model, `SitePage` being duplicated, but the associated models are being removed from the original and associated with the new one.

```
$record = $this->SitePage->find('first', array('condition' => array('SitePage.id' => $id)));
unset($record['SitePage']['id'], $record['SitePageGroup']['id'], $record['SitePageGroup']['SitePageContent']['id'] /* further ids */);
$this->SitePage->create();
$record['SitePage']['name'] = $record['SitePage']['name'].'-copy';
$record['SitePage']['friendly_name'] = $record['SitePage']['friendly_name'].' Copy';
if($this->SitePage->saveAll($record)){
    $this->Session->setFlash('The site page has been saved', 'fo_message');
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}else{
    $this->Session->setFlash('The site page could not be saved. Please, try again.', 'fo_message');
}
```

**Update**

Debugging the record that I'm trying to reset I see the following

```
array(
    'SitePage' => array(
        'name' => 'test',
        'friendly_name' => 'Test',
        'order' => '82',
        'created' => '2015-09-03 19:16:40',
        'modified' => '2015-09-03 19:20:27'
    ),
    'SitePageGroup' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '55e88087-a4dc-4c37-89dc-f9c172b40463',
            'site_page_id' => '55e88078-16c8-46ce-bf02-fa5372b40463',
            'name' => 'group-1',
            'friendly_name' => 'Group 1',
            'order' => '1',
            'created' => '2015-09-03 19:16:55',
            'modified' => '2015-09-03 19:16:55'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '55e8809e-d018-4ebe-a4cf-fbef72b40463',
            'site_page_id' => '55e88078-16c8-46ce-bf02-fa5372b40463',
            'name' => 'group-2',
            'friendly_name' => 'Group 2',
            'order' => '2',
            'created' => '2015-09-03 19:17:18',
            'modified' => '2015-09-03 19:17:18'
        )
    )
)
```

The way I am getting this result is by doing this

```
$sitePage = $this->SitePage->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'SitePage.id' => $id,
    ),
));

unset($sitePage['SitePage']['id'], $sitePage['SitePageGroup']['id'], $sitePage['SitePageGroup']['SitePageContent']['id'], $sitePage['SitePageGroup']['site_page_id'], $sitePage['SitePageGroup']['SitePageContent']['site_page_group_id'] /* further ids */);
debug($sitePage);
die();
```

But also also as you can see in the debug output the 3rd level of associated models are not being included, each of the `SitePageGroup` should also have a `SitePageContent`

I think a simple loop over the array of `SitePageGroup` should reset the id's and set the foreign keys to null, but I guess I also need to somehow include the `SitePageContent` that belongs to the `SitePageGroup` so I can reset those as well.

Comment: HasMany does just that. The Model can "have many" of the associated models. So by defining "SitePage hasMany SitePageGroup", each SitePage can have multiple SitePageGroups. If you want to share common methods between all three models, I would suggest adding a new Model Class which extends AppModel and the three Models all extend the new Model.

Comment: Right I know how associations work, I'm specifically trying to figure out how to duplicate the parent model and keep all associated models along with it.

Comment: What appears to be happening now with the code from the linked question, the associated models are being moved to the duplicated entry and being removed from the original entry.

Comment: Okay. The easiest way to do this would be to fetch all the data, then remove **all** ids from the array and use `saveAll` to save that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that all primary and foreign keys are set to `null` before saving. You only appear to be resetting the primary keys of your models but Cake needs to know that the foreign keys need generating so that they reference the new records.

Before calling `$record` it might be worth using `debug($record);` to check that everything in that array has been set/reset appropriately to ensure the copy will work as expected.

**Update**

Based on the array contents you've posted in your updated question it appears that you are not removing all the primary and foreign keys from your save data. You need to make sure that these are removed from everything you are about to save including the has many associations.

If you look at your array you should be able to see that `unset($sitePage['SitePageGroup']['id'])` will not remove the primary IDs of your `SitePageGroup` data as what you are unsetting doesn't correspond to array paths in your `$sitePage` array.

You can use CakePHP's [Hash utility to remove](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::remove) the primary keys from the array like this:-

```
$sitePage = Hash::remove($sitePage, 'SitePageGroup.{n}.id');
```

And similarly for the foreign keys:-

```
$sitePage = Hash::remove($sitePage, 'SitePageGroup.{n}.site_page_id');
```

Comment: I made an update to the question including the debug output that I'm receiving along with the current code I'm using to achieve it.

Comment: @Jordan, looking at your data you're not unsetting all the primary and foreign keys as suggested in my answer. I've updated my answer to give you a little more detail.

Comment: That was it! I also had to `contain` the deeper associations, clear those out as well, and add the `deep` option as true to the `saveAll()` method so the would also save.